# docker: hide port with --net=host

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile

If docker container is set to `network_mode: host`, any port opened in the container would be **opened on the docker host**, **without requiring** the `-p or -P docker run` option.

How can I **hide the port from public** and make it accessible in `localhost` only.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running with `--net=host`, you're using the host network stack and there are no other Docker controls over how it interacts with the network.  If you want to only listen on a specific interface, your server would **bind**(2) to an address on it, just like any other process running directly on the host.  Most higher-level server packages have an option to listen on some specific address, and you'd set the server to only listen on 127.0.0.1.

Using `--net=host` usually isn't a best practice.  If you omit that option and use the standard Docker networking, then the `docker run -p` option has an option to bind to a specific host IP address.  If your server listens on port 80 inside the container, and you actually want it to listen on port 8888 and only be accessible from the current host, you could

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8888:80 ...
```

(In this latter case the process inside the container *must* listen on 0.0.0.0 or some other equivalent "all addresses" setting, even if you don't intend it to be reachable from off-host.)

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, the reason i used `--net=host` is because without that, inside docker container, `curl http://userservice:2531` gives **couldn't resolve host userservice** error, whereas on host OS i can curl this perfectly. After adding `--net=host` in docker, container was able to resolve the hostname correctly. `http://userservice:2531` is a website hosted on another machine inside the same network. So I thought i'd be able to connect it inside container without a problem. So, at the end is there a way to resolve "lettered" hostname without `--net=host` inside container? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look into [iptables](https://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/)

Comment: any generic way to do it within docker?